# Vue JS, show different menu if user authenticated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

After login i set inside store and inside localStorage the variable `"authenticated" = true`.

How can i check in each page if `authenticated==true` and show different menu element?

(i'm using ssr)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set Vuex state `authenticated` at the point of login.
2. Be sure to clear that when you logging user out or app is starting and you are checking e.g. if JWT is still valid.
3. Set computed variable in components requiring that state.

   `computed() { 
   authenticated () => { return this.$store.state.authenticated }
   }`
4. Use it in your template with `<v-if>`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use Vuex,

1. Set the initial state `{ authenticated: false }` with [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state).
2. Use `this.authenticated` as you would in a vanilla Vue app.

Example:

```
import persistentStorage from 'vue-persistent-storage';

const initialState = {
  authenticated: false
};
Vue.use(persistentStorage, initialState);

Vue.component('my-login', {
  methods: {
    login: function () {
      doLogin()  // call to auth API
        .then(() => { this.authenticated = true })
        .catch(() => { this.authenticated = false })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function () {
    if (loginIsValid) {  // check auth validity upon app bootup
      this.authenticated = true
    } else {
      this.authenticated = false
    }
  }
})
```

Now `authenticated` is available as data in all components and Vue instances. Any changes to `this.authenticated` will be stored in localStorage, and you can use `this.authenticated` as you would in a vanilla Vue app.

If you want to understand how this works, [the code](https://github.com/arve0/vue-persistent-state/blob/master/index.js) is pretty simple. It basically

1. adds a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to make `initialState` available in all Vue instances, and
2. watches for changes and stores them.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of [vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state).